# How to retrieve a list of entities without specifying rowKey from Azure Table Storage in the TableOperation?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

As described here, is seems like there is no method for querying group of entities from azure table storage given only the partitionKey.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tableoperation.retrieve?view=azure-dotnet

I have several groups of partitionsKeys, with different rowKeys. But i want to query all entities just providing the partitionKey.[image]

How can this be done? Is there no way to do this using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table ?
My rowKey values are not incremental/structured, but unique...
Thanks

Update: Syntaks:

```
public async Task<T>> RetrieveEntitysAsync<T>(string paritionKey) where T : TableEntity, new()
{
    TableQuery<MyDataEntity> query = new TableQuery<MyDataEntity>()
        .Where(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "myPartition")
            );


    await CloudTable.ExecuteQuery(query);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve operation is for retrieving a single entity from Table Storage. This is why you will need to specify both PartitionKey and RowKey.

If you want to retrieve multiple entities (e.g. entities matching a particular PartitionKey value), the method you would want to call is [`CloudTable.ExecuteQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.executequery?view=azure-dotnet) and provide a query (e.g. `PartitionKey eq 'your-partition-key-value'`) to that method.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want to do, how would the syntax be? (Check update in post). Do i need to instanciate the CloudTable with a new-up?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the complete code please? It is not clear whether `CloudTable` is an instance variable or not. The code otherwise looks ok to me.

Comment: I think i soved it by properly instanciating a Cloudtable Table with connection string and Tablename. Thanks alot Gaurav!❤

Comment: If i want to resolve this to my own class using the EntityResolver, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.entityresolver-1?view=azure-dotnet, It seems like i need to specify the rowKey. DO i misunderstand this, Or how can i specify only the partition key?